# Explanation of the init.d/scripts Fedora

Tags: fedora, bash, init

Below is a copy of vsftpd, i need some explanations of some of the scripts mentioned below in this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vsftpd
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Short-Description: Very Secure Ftp Daemon
# Description: vsftpd is a Very Secure FTP daemon. It was written completely from
#              scratch
### END INIT INFO

# vsftpd      This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#             standalone vsftpd.
#
# chkconfig: - 60 50
# description: Vsftpd is a ftp daemon, which is the program \
#              that answers incoming ftp service requests.
# processname: vsftpd
# config: /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

RETVAL=0
prog="vsftpd"

start() {
        # Start daemons.

    # Check that networking is up.
    [ ${NETWORKING} = "no" ] && exit 1

    [ -x /usr/sbin/vsftpd ] || exit 1

        if [ -d /etc/vsftpd ] ; then
                CONFS=`ls /etc/vsftpd/*.conf 2>/dev/null`
                [ -z "$CONFS" ] && exit 6
                for i in $CONFS; do
                        site=`basename $i .conf`
                        echo -n $"Starting $prog for $site: "
                        daemon /usr/sbin/vsftpd $i
                        RETVAL=$?
                        echo
                        if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
                                touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
                                break
                        else
                                if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog ]; then
                                        RETVAL=0
                                        break
                                fi
                        fi
                done
        else
                RETVAL=1
        fi
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        # Stop daemons.
        echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
        killproc $prog
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog
        return $RETVAL
}



# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart|reload)
        stop
        start
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
  condrestart|try-restart|force-reload)
        if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog ]; then
            stop
            start
            RETVAL=$?
        fi
        ;;
  status)
        status $prog
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|try-restart|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

**Question I**

What the hell is the difference between the && and || signs in the below commands, and is it just an easy way to do a simple if check or is it completely different to a `if[..something..]; then ..something.. fi`:

```
# Check that networking is up.
    [ ${NETWORKING} = "no" ] && exit 1

    [ -x /usr/sbin/vsftpd ] || exit 1
```

**Question II**

i get what `-eq` and `-gt` is (`equal to`, `greater than`) but is there a simple website that explains what `-x`, `-d` and `-f` are?

**Question III**

It says required starts are `$local_fs $network $named $remote_fs $syslog` but i cant see any where it checks for those.

Any help would be apreciated

Running Fedora 12 on my OS. Script copied from `/etc/init.d/vsftpd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer I**

It's just a shorthand notation.

Here:

```
[ ${NETWORKING} = "no" ] && exit 1
```

It checks if `${NETWORKING}` is set to `"no"`. If this returns false (networking is enabled) then the second part does not get evaluated (exit 1), because it's already false (&&, logical conjunction).

The other way round goes:

```
[ -x /usr/sbin/vsftpd ] || exit 1
```

We have "or" here. So, basically, if *vsftpd* exists, then first part is true and no further checks are made (no exit).

**Answer II**

[man test](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test):

```
   -x FILE
          FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
   -d FILE
          FILE exists and is a directory
   -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
```

**Answer III**

Those parts should be parsed externally. See here for more info on [LSB headers](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging/SysVInitScript#LSB_Header).

Comment: i would vote you up but dont got 15 rep :(

Answer (score 3):

These are all bash-related question, so your main source of information should be a `man bash` (which I agree can be a very... intense experience).

As for your questions:

- The [...] syntax is a shortcut for "if [...]", so that actually *is* a conditional check; "&&" means "and" and "||" means "or" (as in C-derived languages), and both of these operators *don't* evaluate their second operand if the first one is enough to produce an answer; so, if networking is up the instruction after "&&" will *not* be executed (an and condition can't be true if its first operand is false), while if the file "vsftpd" exists the script *will not* exit (an or condition is true if its first operand is true). This syntax (using a conditional to actually *do* something) is mutuated from C, and it's considered confusing but very clever by C hackers.
- "-x" checks for the existence of an executable files, "-d" checks for the existence of a directory, "-f" checks for the existence of a file.
- The commented part at the top doesn't actually consist of comments: they're directives for the `chkconfig` service manager, which will handle dependencies and the startup/shutdown order of services based on those "comments". Yes, I agree this is quite confusing, too.

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept answers now :-)

Comment: Done :D, sry Karol takes the answer though..cause he was first come and both your answers are equally helpfull. i got some understanding from yours and some from his... so gota be fair :D